# Passing confirmation to JSP from servlet, getting errors

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Currently I am attempting to have a page that will return a car, I have a method that creates a new object and passed this to the jsp. The problem I am having the jsp is always expecting the object to arrive resulting in a http status 500.

How do I go about having this object on the page only when the object is created through the servlet. Again this is just to confirm that your request has gone through. My code is below

```
<h4>
<%  ConfirmationBean confirmationBean = (ConfirmationBean)request.getAttribute("confirmation");
    if( !confirmationBean.getConfirmation().equals("") || !confirmationBean.getConfirmation().equals(null)){
        out.println(confirmationBean.getConfirmation());
    }
%>
</h4>
```

and the stack trace I am getting is below.

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:579)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: You should check if  `request.getAttribute("confirmation")` return something first. Didn't used JSP like this is a while but I believe this should be `null`. But you should see how to use `JSTL` with JSP. This is cleaner and easier to use. If you have the time, this is a must with JSP.

Comment: Stacktrace without a complete message is useless. We know where the error is, but not **what** the error is. Anyway, I'd expect the error is a NPE, i.e. the `confirmationBean` is `null` - if so, add `confirmationBean != null` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if the return of this `request.getAttribute("confirmation")` is `null`

```
if(request.getAttribute("confirmation")!=null){
         //go ahead
}
```